# Make file for both 32 and 64 bit builds

Tags: makefile

I need to create a make file which will allow the user to choose to create either a 64 or 32 bit build.  I'm new to make and am not sure what the best way to do this would be.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: ASL? (architecture/system/langage?)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [this article](http://mad-scientist.net/make/multi-arch.html). The long and short of it is to have separate output directories for each architecture, and show make how to find the source from each of them.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is assumed that you using either Linux/UNIX.

```
LBITS := $(shell getconf LONG_BIT)
ifeq ($(LBITS),64)
   # do 64 bit some stuff
else
   # do 32 bit stuff here
endif
```

.